# Ionic 4 navigate

Tags: ionic

Boa tarde, sou novo na plataforma angular/Ionic, estou estudando e tenho uma função:

```
async update() {

 this.contactService.updateservice(this.frmcontactdetail.value).subscribe();
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: 'Contact update successfully',
      duration: 2000
    });
    toast.present();
    this.router.navigate(['/contact']);
  }
```

o dado é atualizado no banco de dados, mas quando redirecionado a rota 'this.router.navigate(['/contact'])', o mesmo ainda se encontrada com os dados antigos,não atualizando de forma alguma.
*Pagina Contact

```
list() {
    try {
       this.contactService.listservice().subscribe(dados => this.contact = dados);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('erro encontrado ' + error);
    }
  }
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Alguém por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Você está usando um `Behaviour Subject` ou `Subject` em vez de um Observable ?

Porque assim, a sua intenção é atualizar as informações e enviar essa atualização para todos as funções que estão cadastradas para "observar" essa atualização.

No seu `contactService`, deveria ser assim:

```
...

/**
 * O evento que irá monitorar as alterações do contato
 */
public onContactChangeEvent: Subject<Contact>;

/**
 * Construtor do serviço
 */
constructor() {
   // Se você quiser inicializar esse evento com algum valor, 
   // você deveria usar o Behaviour Suject.
   // ficando assim:         = new BehaviourSubject(contactInfo);
   this.onContactChangeEvent = new Subject<Contact>();
}

...
```

E para você "ouvir" as atualizações, você usa:

```
// Para manter uma aplicação concisa, você deve atribuir o resultado dessa inscrição e salvar 
// Normalmente eu coloco em ionViewDidLoad ou ionViewDidEnter
this.onContactSubscription = this.onContactChangeEvent.subscribe(contact => console.log(contact));

...

// E quando a sua página onde essa inscrição foi descarregada da memória, ou o usuário sair da página, você desinscreve a inscrição.
// Normalmente eu coloco no ionViewDidUnload ou ionViewDidLeave
this.onContactSubscription && this.onContactSubscription.unsubscribe();
```

E para enviar as atualizações para que em todos os lugares que ele esteja ouvindo, você usa:

```
this.onContactChangeEvent.next(newContactInfo);
```

Comment: Perfeito,FUNCIONOU, Meu Muito Obrigado.